# Async takes longer than sequential execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to do a very basic task in c++ using multi threading, I have noticed that running this code using lower numbers of threads is actually faster than using multiple threads.

I have tried switching to thread(...), adding and removing mutex, but it still is either the same or slower.

```
struct threadResults
{
    int64_t threadSize;
    int64_t sum =0;
    int32_t min_val = std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max();
    int32_t max_val = std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min();
};
void doCalculation(int thread_num, std::vector<int> rand_values, int32_t numPerThread, threadResults* myThreadResult, int remainder)
{
    if(remainder!=0&&thread_num==0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<numPerThread+remainder;++i)
        {
            myThreadResult->sum += rand_values[i];
            if(myThreadResult->min_val>rand_values[i])
            {
                myThreadResult->min_val = rand_values[i];
            }
            if(myThreadResult->max_val<rand_values[i])
            {
                myThreadResult->max_val = rand_values[i];
            }
        }
    }
    else if(remainder!=0&&thread_num!=0)
    {
        int start = (numPerThread*thread_num)+remainder;
        for(int i=start;i<numPerThread+start;++i) {
            myThreadResult->sum += rand_values[i];
            if (myThreadResult->min_val > rand_values[i]) {
                myThreadResult->min_val = rand_values[i];
            }
            if (myThreadResult->max_val < rand_values[i]) {
                myThreadResult->max_val = rand_values[i];
            }
        }
    }
    else if(remainder==0)
    {
        int start = (numPerThread*thread_num);
        for(int i=start;i<numPerThread+start;++i) {
            myThreadResult->sum += rand_values[i];
            if (myThreadResult->min_val > rand_values[i]) {
                myThreadResult->min_val = rand_values[i];
            }
            if (myThreadResult->max_val < rand_values[i]) {
                myThreadResult->max_val = rand_values[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
    std::future<void> myThreads[num_threads];


    auto start = sc::high_resolution_clock::now();

    //TODO:  Implement multithreaded code to populate the above stat values
    for(int i=0;i<num_threads;i++) {
         myThreads[i] = async(std::launch::async, doCalculation, i, rand_values, numPerThread, &myThreadResults[i], remainder);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<num_threads;i++) {
        myThreads[i].get();
    }

    for(threadResults t : myThreadResults)
    {
        sum += t.sum;
        if(t.min_val<min_val)
        {
            min_val = t.min_val;
        }
        if(t.max_val>max_val)
        {
            max_val = t.max_val;
        }
    }

    auto end = sc::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

I expect running this code with 1 thread to take more time than 2+ threads, but this is not the case.

```
$ ./sumit 10000000 1 0
Elapsed Time: 101228us
Sum: 101555736
Min: -100000
Max: 100000
Avg: 10.1556
$ ./sumit 10000000 2 0
Elapsed Time: 142738us
Sum: 101555736
Min: -100000
Max: 100000
Avg: 10.1556
```

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, this is obnoxiously big and hard to pull apart.

Comment: What @Omnifarious said.  Also, compile with retail optimizations fully on (-O3 or Release build settings).

Comment: Call me crazy, but isn't that `if(remainder!=0&&thread_num==0)` block functionally equivalent to the subsequent `else if(remainder!=0&&thread_num!=0)` block.  For that matter, aren't all three of those blocks of code the same set of calculations?

Comment: @selbie - I gave up on the weird contorted logic in there and wrote a program that I think is what the OP wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
void doCalculation(int thread_num, std::vector<int> rand_values, int32_t numPerThread, threadResults* myThreadResult, int remainder)
```

to this:

```
void doCalculation(int thread_num, std::vector<int> const &rand_values, int32_t numPerThread, threadResults* myThreadResult, int remainder)
```

and I bet things will get a lot faster.

I wrote a program that does what your does. And I shall paste the whole thing in here, which is really what you ought to have done if you wanted more constructive help:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <future>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

using ::std::int64_t;
using ::std::uint32_t;
using ::std::future;

struct threadResults
{
    int64_t sum;
    int32_t min_val;
    int32_t max_val;
};

using randvec_t = ::std::vector<int>;

threadResults doCalculation(randvec_t::iterator begin, randvec_t::iterator end)
{
    if (begin == end) {
        throw ::std::range_error("Range to iterate over must not be empty!");
    }
    threadResults results{0, *begin, *begin};
    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
        auto const cur = *i;
        results.sum += cur;
        if (results.min_val > cur) {
            results.min_val = cur;
        } else if (results.max_val < cur) {
            results.max_val = cur;
        }
    }
    return results;
}

int main(int argc, char const * const argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        fmt::print(stderr, "Usage: {} <num_to_sum> <threads_to_use>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int const size = ::std::stoi(argv[1]);
    int const nthreads = ::std::stoi(argv[2]);

    if (size <= nthreads || nthreads < 0) {
        fmt::print(stderr, "You must have more elements than threads and neither may be negative.");
    }

    randvec_t elements;
    elements.reserve(size);

    {
        //std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(5);
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, ::std::numeric_limits<randvec_t::value_type>::max());

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            elements.push_back(dis(gen));
        }
    }

    namespace sc = ::std::chrono;

    auto start = sc::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ::std::vector<::std::future<threadResults>> futures;
    futures.reserve(nthreads);
    for (unsigned int start = 0; start < elements.size();) {
        unsigned int const end = start + (elements.size() - start) / (nthreads - futures.size());
        futures.push_back(::std::async(::std::launch::async, doCalculation, elements.begin() + start, elements.begin() + end));
        start = end;
    }
    threadResults aggregate{0, 0, 0};
    bool first = true;
    for (auto &future: futures) {
        if (first) {
            aggregate = future.get();
            first = false;
        } else {
            auto this_result = future.get();
            aggregate.sum += this_result.sum;
            aggregate.min_val = ::std::min(this_result.min_val, aggregate.min_val);
            aggregate.max_val = ::std::max(this_result.max_val, aggregate.max_val);
        }
    }
    auto end = sc::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = end - start;
    fmt::print("Duration: {}us\n", duration / sc::microseconds(1));
    fmt::print("     sum: {}\n", aggregate.sum);
    fmt::print("     min: {}\n", aggregate.min_val);
    fmt::print("     max: {}\n", aggregate.max_val);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the results of running this program on my nice 16 hardware thread Ryzen 7 (I use [takoshell](https://takoshell.org), hence my weird prompt):

```
 /tmp/so_problem
$ ./a.out 100000000 1
Duration: 76676us
     sum: 107373414219986326
     min: 11
     max: 2147483633
 /tmp/so_problem
$ ./a.out 100000000 4
Duration: 20534us
     sum: 107373414219986326
     min: 11
     max: 2147483633
 /tmp/so_problem
$ ./a.out 100000000 8
Duration: 17177us
     sum: 107373414219986326
     min: 11
     max: 2147483633
```

I'm not exactly sure why the results sort of bottom out between 4 and 8 threads. Now... **that** would be an interesting question. I strongly suspect it's memory bandwidth related.

Note how my program is missing a lot of the weird nonsensical fluff that yours has.